# Problem of diagnostic test

Tags: probability

Consider the statement:

In a city, $1 \%$ of the population is known to have a rare disease. A test is available to detect this disease, which has a true positive rate of $99 \%$ and a false positive rate of $ 2 \%$.

First, you want to determine the probability that a person has the disease. I try to solve the problem, considering the following events

A:The person is really sick

B:The test marks true

I think that we have.

$P(A)=0.1$, $P(B \mid A)=0.9$ and $P(B \mid A^c)=0.02$

So, we can apply Bayes Theorem

$P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(B \mid A) P(A)}{P(B \mid A^c) P(A^c)+P(B \mid A) P(A)}=\frac{0.9 \times0.01}{(0.9)(0.01)+(0.02)(1-0.01)} \approx 0.31$

And if **I want to find the probability that a test is positive**, I think it is enough to take the total probability of the event $B$.

But I am not sure of this reasoning, any suggestions? I appreciate it.

Comment: Is the true positive rate 90% or 99%? The statement of the problem and your calculations don't match on that point. Otherwise your reasoning seems sound

Comment: Well, according to the statement it is $99 \%$ now that I think about it I should have put 0.99. My mistake, but this would be the only detail?

Comment: Everything else looks right to me